# How to zip 3 lists of different sizes

Tags: python

I have 3 lists of different size.

```
A=[1500,1000,500]
B=[159,179]
C=[6,9,12,18]
```

I want it to multiply and get 24(AxBxC) lists like

```
[[1500,159,6],[1000,159,9],[500,159,12],[1500,159,18],.....[500,179,18]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the three lists. You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
my_lists = [A,B,C]
[i for i in product(*my_lists)]

[(1500, 159, 6),
 (1500, 159, 9),
 (1500, 159, 12),
 (1500, 159, 18),
 (1500, 179, 6),
 (1500, 179, 9),
 (1500, 179, 12),
 (1500, 179, 18),
 (1000, 159, 6),
 (1000, 159, 9),
...
```

Comment: Thanks! It was  really helpful